# two-way binding in angular not updating

Tags: angularjs

I have created a plnkr which demonstrates a problem that I am trying to solve.  When you click the link in the plnkr, you will see a textfield. This textfield is bound with ng-model to myCtrl.foo, and in that controller is a $watch looking at the controller's foo property and then setting $scope.num to a random number. You will notice the random number never changes even though the watcher is clearly firing (via a console.log).

http://plnkr.co/edit/wpFPFeRC6CFFjLOa9QQw

Can anyone explain why this is not working, and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: No, angular isn't "broken"; thus it must be the code using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is it working: http://plnkr.co/edit/tagldRNsgLXUhoGfZ2Un?p=preview

Did two things, first assigned all primitive bindings to an object called test. You can see why it is best to do this here: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot

Second, put the controller around the views to ensure they share a scope and pulled it out of ui-router (as I know next to nothing about ui-router and whatever magic it does)

Answer (score 1):

#### Here is what happens

When you define your routes:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider) {   $stateProvider
    .state('items', {
      url: '/items/:item_id',
      views: {
        'my-view': {
          controller: 'myController as myCtrl',
          templateUrl: 'my-view.html'
        },
        'main@': {
          controller: 'myController',
          templateUrl: 'main.html'
        },
      }
    })
});
```

you assign 2 different views to use the same controller, which is OK, but a controller in Angular is not a singleton. It is a constructor function. Meaning that both controllers (and their scope) will not be the same instance, but 2 different instances.

So the controller and the scope in view 1 will not be the same controller and scope as in view 2.

The controller will be instantiated twice with a different scope so the changes made in the scope of view 1 will not reflect the changes made in the scope of view 2 (as they have a different scope).

You can see this if you add the following lines to your controller:

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  console.log('myController scope id: ' + $scope.$id);
  console.dir($scope);
  // Your code here
});
```

The log will show:

```
myController scope id: 003
myController scope id: 004
```

#### Possible solutions

Avoiding this boils down to personal preference. Here are some valid options:

- use events to communicate between scopes and send an event when `num` is updated
- use a service to store `num` centrally
- store `num` in the $rootScope

Hope that helps!